# Proper type casting in a shell script for use with while loop and modulus

Tags: shell-script, test, random, numeric-data, expr

I am trying to write a script to get a random, even hex number. I have found the the `openssl` command has a convenient option for creating random hex numbers. Unfortunately, I need it to be even and my script has a type casting error somewhere. Bash thinks that my newly generated hex number is a string, so when I try to mod it by 2, the script fails. Here is what I have so far:

```
...
hexVal="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
while [ `expr $hexVal % 2` -ne 0 ]
do
    hexVal="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
done
...
```

I have tried various other combinations as well, to no avail. If someone could tell me what is wrong with my syntax, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using bash

To generate an even random number in hex:

```
$ printf '%x\n' $((2*$RANDOM))
d056
```

Or:

```
$ hexVal=$(printf '%x\n' $((2*$RANDOM)))
$ echo $hexVal
f58a
```

To limit the output to smaller numbers, use modulo, `%`:

```
$ printf '%x\n' $(( 2*$RANDOM % 256 ))
4a
```

#### Using openssl

If you really want to use a looping solution with `openssl`:

```
while hexVal="$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
do
    ((0x$hexVal % 2 == 0)) && break
done
```

The `0x` signals that the number which follows is hex.

#### Rules for casting numbers in bash

From `man bash`:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  **A
>   leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal.**  Otherwise, numbers take the
>   form [base#]n, where the optional base  is  a  decimal    number 
>   between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number
>   in that base.  If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used.  When
>   specifying n, the digits greater< than 9 are    represented by the
>   lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, @, and _, in that order.  If
>   base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may
>   be  used  interchangeably    to represent numbers between 10 and 35. [Emphasis added]

Comment: I decided to stick with the while loop. Thanks much for the help, works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

What about this instead

```
printf "%0x\n" $(( ($RANDOM*2) & 0xff))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hexVal=1

while (( 16#$hexVal % 2))
do
    hexVal=$(openssl rand -hex 1)
done

printf "%x [%d]\n"  0x$hexVal  0x$hexVal
```